# Adaptive Payment using Paypal in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I want to make a payment process in my iOS application using PayPal API.

There will a specific scenario-

Let suppose there is three users, User1, User2 and User3. If a User1 want to make payment to User3. But it will not be done directly.

- He will press Payment Button in my app, PayPal login screen comes
- User1 will pay to User2.
- After some time, User1 will press Release Payment button in my application, then 85% amount of total amount from User2 PayPal account automatically transfer to a third account.
- There will be one more thing if User2 want to cancel payment of User3 then he can cancel in that case 85% amount of total amount will transfer to  User1.

We have credit card details, PayPal email, Password everything for User2's PayPal account. But for User1 and User2's account we have access to PayPal email address only.

I have searched a lot, I found PayPal MPL SDK for this and read about chained payment and implemented this. But in this case I am able to pay User2 and User1 simultaneously on click of Payment Button. There is no use Payment Release button. I have looked Pre Approval Payment in PayPal but I don't think so it will work my case.

Any suggestion or help will be appreciated.

Comment: You should never be collecting password for any third party user. I would be shocked if that's allowed as part of the terms of service.

Comment: I am not doing so, I am only using email id's for third party users like User1 and User3. I am the User2 so I can use my email and password there should not be any issue.